# Retrieve Cubes that Share a Vertex

Tags: 3d

Suppose that we have a world with an infinite number of cubes, each of which are 1x1x1 in size and have integral coordinates, e.g. (1, 2, 3)

Given that C is a cube at (X<sub>C</sub>, Y<sub>C</sub>, Z<sub>C</sub>) and that P is a vertex of that cube with coordinates (X<sub>P</sub>, Y<sub>P</sub>, Z<sub>P</sub>), what are the coordinates of the other 7 cubes that have the vertex P?

X<sub>C</sub> - X<sub>P</sub> = 0 or -1 *and* Y<sub>C</sub> - Y<sub>P</sub> = 0 or -1 *and* Z<sub>C</sub> - Z<sub>P</sub> = 0 or -1

Comment: How do you model the coordinates of a cube? Seemingly, you don't use the coordinates of the $8$ vertices whose convex hull the given cube is. So what do you do? Do you take the center as its coordinate?

Comment: @Stefan, I take the "Lowest" vertex for its location, so that CP - XP is either 0 or -1 (and the same applies to the Y and Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the cube with vertices $\{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1) \}$. If I understand your comment, you would index this cube at $(0,0,0)$.
The $7$ other cubes that share this vertex are indexed at $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, $(0,-1,-1)$, $(0,0,-1)$, $(-1,0,-1)$, $(0,-1,-1)$, and $(-1,-1,-1)$.

Now given any vertex $P = (x,y,z)$, there are $8$ cubes sharing this vertex and these are indexed at $(x,y,z)$, $(x-1,y,z)$, $(x,y-1,z)$, $(x,y-1,z-1)$, $(x,y,z-1)$, $(x-1,y,z-1)$, $(x,y-1,z-1)$, and $(x-1,y-1,z-1)$ respectively. If we remove the index of the cube we started with ( namely $(X_C, Y_C, Z_C)$ in your notation ), the remaining indices yield the desired answer.

Comment: Are you sure that this is right? Those would be the cubes around C but I asked for the cubes around P (which can be any vertex of C)

Comment: @Lolums I misread your question, let me fix that.